# asp.net .exe is not a valid win32 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

Ive wrote a simple .exe console app using asp.net 4 and c# that I plan on running as a scheduled task on a server. It all runs fine on my local machine but I've just copied it up to the server and its throwing the error "is not a valid Win32 application"

the server is a windows server 2003 with .net version 2,3 and 4 installed

thansk

Answer (score -1):

If the version of your Windows Server 2003 is 64 bit, you should compile the app to x64 or anycpu.

Comment: brilliant thanks ill give that a try and get back, any idea how I find out what version I have compiled it to? and how I compile it to 64bit?

Comment: Ok I've done that, but I now have the error "The image file .... is valid, but is for a machine type other than the current machine"